# ¿Cómo pongo opacidad a la imagen de fondo de mi página?

Tags: css, css3

¿Cómo puedo ponerle opacidad solo a la imagen que tengo como `background`? Siempre que intente ponerle opacidad se aplica a toda la pagina. Gracias

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], te recomiendo agregar el código que llevas hecho aunque contenga errores

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una nueva capa de color blanco o negro y aplicar el siguiente atributo para difuminarla

```
div {
opacity: 0.5,
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos responder a preguntas de baja calidad ya que pueden terminar cerradas. En su lugar, orientamos al OP para que se más específico en su pregunta y luego procedemos a responder. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.

Answer (score 0):

Asignale una id al elemento y luego modificalo desde tu archivo css, ejemplo:

html:

```
<img id="img-fondo" href="..." />
```

css:

```
#img-fondo{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```